# myquery taking too long time in mysql

Tags: mysql

My transactionDetail table has 300 million data.For getting data for my query its taking very long time.

Below is my query

```
 select 
 MerchantId as y_m,BoothId ,
 TransactionTypeId , 
 count(Amount) , 
 sum(Amount)  
 from TransactionDetail  
 where TransactionDate>='2014-02-26' 
 and TransactionDate<'2019-02-27' 
 and not (BoothId like 'TEST%')  
 and MerchantId in (select MerchantId from MerchantGroup where  MerchantClassId='MD-SAFAL') 
 group by MerchantId, BoothId, TransactionTypeId 
 order by y_m asc, BoothId asc, TransactionTypeId asc;
```

TransactionDetail table has below keys and indexes

- PRIMARY KEY (`TransactionId`),

Indexes are below

- KEY `idxTransactionDetail003` (`MerchantId`),
- KEY `idxTransactionDetail004` (`TransactionDate`)

MerchantGroup table has index on MerchantId column

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. There are lots of questions on query optimizatiopn here - do take some time to read some of them. Note which ones are upvoted or downvoted/closed and the reasons for this. Note which ones have been given useful answers. You have described *some* of the schema involved in the query (but not all) but have provided no details on the data distribution nor the metrics. Your starting point for looking at query performance should always be the `EXPLAIN` plan.

Answer (score 1):

you could add  a composite index   on TransactionDetail  columns  ( MerchantId, TransactionDate, BoothId )

and you could use a inner join instead of IN clause

and use not like instead of not  (  like   )

```
    select d.MerchantId as y_m
    ,d.BoothId 
    ,d.TransactionTypeId 
    , count(d.Amount) , sum(d.Amount)  
    from TransactionDetail d
    INNER JOIN (
        select MerchantId 
        from MerchantGroup 
        where MerchantClassId='MD-SAFAL'
    ) t t.MerchantId = d.MerchantId
    where d.TransactionDate>='2014-02-26' 
        and d.TransactionDate<'2019-02-27' 
    and d.BoothId not like 'TEST%'  
    group by d.MerchantId, d.BoothId, d.TransactionTypeId 
    order by y_m asc, d.BoothId asc, d.TransactionTypeId asc;
```